# Checking for class dlls on application launch message

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies

Is there any way to check for your class dll files? Let's say:

Example.exe has MC.dll and LOD.dll

If I put Example.exe without the dll files on my desktop, it will give you the "Microsoft .NET Framework" error.

What I want to do is find something to check for the dlls and see if it's in the same directory as the .exe application instead of it giving you the Framework error. I want people to know what is going on, instead of people not knowing what to do. Thanks!

Comment: Our time is precious too.

Comment: have you tried using reflection to open the assembly and just catching any exceptions? Will only work for one ref at a time though

Comment: Also, why would they not know what to do? Maybe you need to build an installer?

Comment: @Rick: Then why post here? I don't appreciate your inappropriate comment. @DustinDavis: It might be obvious, but you know some people aren't too bright when it comes to errors, all they can basically say is "HELPPPP"... so it will value my product for people to actually know what is going on.

Comment: @user747815 - You'll find that saying "I didn't want to waste my time searching the web" will not get you positive results around here. This site is for when you've already thought about it, tried searching the web, and couldn't find what you needed.

Comment: @user747815 why not just create an installer. I don't get what the root problem is. Are you creating spyware?

Answer (score 2):

You should know the directory the .dll files should be in, so just check to make sure they are there. If they aren't then show a message box or something. This obviously must be done from an external application which would then launch the program, as otherwise it would never even get to run the check. (Thanks to DustinDavis for pointing out the need to clarify)

Comment: assuming you mean an external app that has a list of required references and it checks for those, right?

Comment: Yes, something that would launch example.exe if all the references were found, else show a message. Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event.  This event is fired when the application cannot resolve a particular assembly.  You can then either provide an alternate location to find the assembly or you can throw up an error message.

Comment: this can be handled inside of executing assembly, yes?

Comment: right, just subscribe to the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve event, then you can react to any assembly that cannot be resolved at runtime.  However, the resolution may not happen until you use one of the types from that assembly.

Comment: that's pretty awesome. I didn't know that.